In the cmd.exe environment, do the wildcards * and *.* function the same?
I've noticed that in the cmd, using either (*) or (*.*) will match all files and directories. For example, when setting the parameters of a console application to (*.*), it matches not only files in the current directory but also directories. How can wildcards be used to match only files? Was this designed to work like this initially (matching both files and directories)? Currently, my solution is to loop through the argv parameters when dealing with (*) and check if each is a directory. Is there a simpler method than this? Additionally, in a Windows environment, without using API functions or the stat function, are there any other C functions or CRT (C Runtime Library) functions that can determine if a target is a file or a directory?

See: CMD: `.` or just `*`?`.

@gregspears depends what api: NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex] or FindFirstFile[Ex] used. FindFirstFileEx check for *.* and replace it to * before call to NtQueryDirectoryFileEx. Because most apps, like cmd or pwsh use FindFirstFileEx we view same effect for *.* and *

It is an OS issue, not a programming issue or C language issue.  It may be an issue if the system or library API calls you make to process wildcards, but without the code you are using to do that it is likely off-topic.  You mention cmd.exe and C/argv, but they are not related. Even if you launch your code from cmd.exe that is irrelevant.  The only time cmd.exe would be relevant is if you were issuing commands via system().

* and *.* not the same, if use NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex] api. but FindFirstFile[Ex] api scpecial check for *.* mask and replace it to *. so same it or no, depend from what api to use. in any case, the best use * if we need enumerate all files without filter. if we need exactly *.* logic (only files containing . symbol) need use NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex]
